# UIScrollView only scrolls with text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I recently updated my xcode to 4.5 but now my UIScrollView Doesn't work anymore, in my previous xcode I made the scrollview at the exact same way and placed a imageview background and some buttons in it, they scroll along when I scroll.

Now with this new xcode when I place something in it, it doesn't scroll at all. Only when I put textview in it and make the text longer then the screen then it will scroll, but even then when I place a button on it the button won't scroll along, just the text. It's realy annoying and I don't know what Im doing wrong.. I've been trying to find a solution to this all day.

my ScrollView is placed in my view and got size 320,480.

in my ViewDidLoad I have:

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 481)];
```

I also have a picture to make my setup more clear, When I run the project in this picture it does scroll because of the text length. the image background is 320x960 but the picture doesn't scroll along it should go to the bottom where to color becomes more dark.. I hope you understand what I mean.

[image]

**Extra**

I made a video showing what I do, showing that it doesnt scroll when I put something in it

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzYTWLiIC8g&feature=youtu.be

Comment: what is your scrollView height and width ?

Comment: UIScrollView is 320x481 but changing that doesn't change a thing, ofcourse it changes the size of the UIScrollView but the background image still doesn't scroll along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your `scrollView` `contentSize`s **height** more than its original **height** then it would be vertically scrollable for sure.

Try this -

```
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

Then see it scrolls or not.

Comment: Oke I tried it but it doesn't work! the background still doesn't scroll along and if I place a label or button it doesn't scroll along either, only the text scrolls It's realy strange I tried everything And it worked perfectly fine on the previous Xcode.

If I set the content size to scroll horizontaly then labels and buttons etc do scroll along to the sides its realy strange and frustrating

Comment: It feels a little like the background image is not in the view but I did it a hundred times to be sure its in it :P

Comment: Lets try it only one scrollView with one UIImageView.
take one scrollView with (0.0,0.0,320.0,100.0) frame and then add one UIImageView on this scrollView pragmatically with (60.0,80.0,200.0,100) frame and then set scrollView content size (320,200)....then see what happen and let me know ...

Comment: I did what you say, it doesn't scroll .. im getting so frustrated :p

Comment: :D not possible - Actually i dont have my mac right now other wise i would give you proper code ... I youlw let you know tomorrow .. :)

Comment: I know right its so annoying I was thinking about reinstalling xcode but I had this problem last night on my imac and now on my macbook so it's not about the installation either.. on my previous xcode it did work. Let me give you some extra information: when I remove the one uiimageview and leave the scrollview empty then I can scroll I can see the little scroll bar go up and down then .. :S As soon as I place anything in It it stops scrolling ..

Comment: I've made a video showing that it scrolls empty but when I put something in it it doesnt scroll http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzYTWLiIC8g&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Yeah i saw - Select simulator > Go to Hardware > Device > select iPhone(Retina 3.5-inch) and run your project in this and then tell me what happen .....

Comment: It doesn't change anything .. this is not normal is it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17169/discussion-between-vakul-saini-and-donny)

Comment: "Use auto layout" was on on, is has to be off and that will solve this problem